# IntelliJ IDEA - Maven2 - Installation

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I download from private repository a project and when I try to install I show the error that I need a Maven2. The problem is that when I download the IntelliJ IDEA, I download the last version that provided Maven3.

The question is... It's possible change the version Maven in the IntelliJ IDEA?

Because other problem is when I install the project show the next error in console.

```
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-site-plugin/2.0-beta-7/maven-site-plugin-2.0-beta-7.jar
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:maven-plugin:2.0-beta-7' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
[INFO] Skipping missing optional mojo: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:attach-descriptor
Downloading: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-install-plugin/2.2/maven-install-plugin-2.2.jar
[WARNING] Unable to get resource 'org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:maven-plugin:2.2' from repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2): Error transferring file: repo1.maven.org
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] A required plugin was not found: Plugin could not be found - check that the goal name is correct: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

Try downloading the file manually from the project website.

Then, install it using the command: 
    mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -DartifactId=maven-install-plugin -Dversion=2.2 -Dpackaging=maven-plugin -Dfile=/path/to/file

Alternatively, if you host your own repository you can deploy the file there: 
    mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=org.apache.maven.plugins -DartifactId=maven-install-plugin -Dversion=2.2 -Dpackaging=maven-plugin -Dfile=/path/to/file -Durl=[url] -DrepositoryId=[id]


  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:maven-plugin:2.2

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)


  org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:maven-plugin:2.2

from the specified remote repositories:
  central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
```

But I think that the problem it's not the proxy, the problem is that repo1.maven.org is for maven3.

Comment: I don't think you need Maven 2. How did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: The first thing is that you are accessing central via http instead of https ...furthermore the question is which Java version you are using? Apart from that the error message does not tell if you have no access to internet based on proxy/firewall restrictions?

Comment: **1)** Please share your pom in the post. **2)** Check that you have access to central maven repo on the url which is in the pos. We've had a similar problem in the other question, where the Windows firewall was blocking the computer access to the maven repo, see my answer here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775550/can-not-resolve-symbol-security-in-spring-boot-application/56775643#56775643.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA (version 2019.1.3 on Mac) Setting Path to change Maven home directory.

`Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven`

Comment: It is highly unlikely that the OP really needs a different Maven version. He/She just thinks so.

Comment: @JFMeier the OP's question is very clear. But it's not clear what s/he wants.