# Spring boot on IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

this is my first time ever working with a framework, I decided to learn Spring Boot to create a web app project.
I have followed some tutorials, and the steps were (for most of the videos):

1. go to start.spring.io, add the "Spring Web" dependency, select Maven project and then download the zip file.
2. import the project on IntelliJ as a Maven project.

But the problem is that, as shown in the screenshots:
it says: Cannot resolve symbol 'springframework'
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrkq0.png)
and as for the POM file,
"Failure to transfer org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.5.2 from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository"

as well as: Project '...' not found
Dependency '...' not found
Plugin '...' not found
[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cDx3.png)

Please let me know, what steps did I miss.
Thank you

Comment: Are you by any chance behind a proxy?

Comment: yes i am, why? @peterulb

Comment: Failure to transfer sounds like a connection issue to the central maven repository. You might need to try this https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-http-proxy.html

Comment: Or if this doesn't work, try to configure maven directly, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15334394/could-not-transfer-artifact-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-surefire-pluginpom2

Comment: If you trying it from your office network then you might need to add the settings.xml in .m2 folder to let maven know custom configuration which  you wish to use.

Comment: This project is opened in a network behind proxy. Usually a `settings.xml` is included in the project root directory or you need to ask your colleagues for that `settings.xml`. `settings.xml` contains data such as local repository location, alternate remote repository servers, and authentication information which is to be placed  in `~/.m2`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please check if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775550/can-not-resolve-symbol-security-in-spring-boot-application/56775643 can be useful, I guess we've met the same problem of proxy or firewall which blocked the downloading from maven repo. Also please try to run maven from the command line instead of IDE.

Comment: All the possible solutions are addressed here-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074063/maven-error-failure-to-transfer

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you can access "https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2". And check the HTTP proxy settings from `Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings | HTTP Proxy`. Select `No proxy` if you don't need it for accessing the Maven repo. Also, try to disable the downloaded 3rd party plugins temporarily and restart your IDE.