# dependency spring-boot-starter-security not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

i am trying to use the spring boot starter security to secure my application. However it is not working for some reasons. Here are the imports that use the dependency:

```
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity
```

For everyone I get the error `can not reslov symbol security`. I found that other guys have the same Problem like here [Can not resolve symbol "security" in spring boot application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56775550/can-not-resolve-symbol-security-in-spring-boot-application). But none of these solutions seem to work for me.

Here is how the dependency is decleared in the pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Also if I go to dependency tab in my IDE it lists spring-boot-starter-security together with the others. And also i can run `mvn clean install` without any errors. Therefor I do not understand what exactly is going wrong.
Any help is apprichiated.

Comment: Have you tried a specific version? for example an older version may work - https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security/2.6.3

Comment: Don't specify a version if you use Spring BOot to manage your dependencies, that will only lead to mixing different versions of frameworks with different errors/issues as a result!. If thte `mvn clean install` works, then the dependencies are there and it is your IDE which is drunk. Depending on which IDE clear the caches and rebuild indexes.

Comment: Thanks, the reloading worked. It is pretty stupid the IDE doesn't  reload them at all if you don't say so.

Comment: Yep. Reloading is not working correctly sometimes. You need to restart IDE, stupid things.